# Fetch Facebook Mutual friends between me and another User

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i want to fetch Facebook Mutual friends in my ios App

this is my try to get mutual friends i call with this Link

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/mutual_friends/%@?fields=installed",fbuserId]
```

it give for me Error code 5 
and when i use `@"me/friends"`
it returns result 
i also try using graph api explorer it gives unknown path

[APi Graph Explorer try](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fmutual_friends%2F1310347645&version=v2.1)

ALso my app have user_friends Permission 
can any one tell me the correct path ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user.context/mutual_friends

Comment: @CBroe can you modify my Link 
i do not know how to put context 
me/mutual_friends/%@?fields=installed"

Comment: Using this with `/me` doesn’t make much sense – you want to find the mutual friends between your current app user and another user, right? Then you need to use the (app-scoped) user id of that other user.

Comment: @CBroe i also trying this but no result 

[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/mutual_friends/%@?fields=installed",MyFbId,fbuserId]

Comment: Don’t invent you own “syntax”, but follow the one given in the documentation.

Comment: it works in v 1.0 but now it does not work 
i want to fetch mutual friends in that way 
is it possible 
in another way can you give me link in Graph APi Explorer fetching the mutual friends between me and another user

Comment: In API v2.0 you can only get friends that are also using the app.

Comment: @CBroe ok Can you Tell Me how can i fetch Mutual Friends in 
Graph Api Explorer can you send me the Link which fetch the Mutual Friends only between two Profile Ids ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong endpoint syntax, as @CBroe already pointed out, and which is also clear from the docs.

You need to use

```
/{user-id}.context/mutual_friends
```

The `{user-id}` is the user you're interested in, and the "other" user is the one which Access Token was used for the request. This ONLY works for users which are both already users of your app.

Comment: did you mean for example 
like this /1310347645.724379967/mutual_friends i use it and give to me Unknown path components i will be thankful if you give me example

Comment: I described everything. How hard can this be? And why Do you remove parts which are neccessary?

Comment: i am really sorry but i am beginner in ios and Using FaceBook SDK 
i use what you see but it gives to me  Unknown path components kindly can you give example

Comment: i make exactly what you said but it gives Unknown path components

Comment: @CBroe if you do not believe me can you try it on this Link 

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=552779567.context%2Fmutual_friends&version=v2.0

Comment: That's because you're using a global user_id, which is not allowed by Graph API v2.0.  Use an app-scoped user_id and everything is fine.

Comment: The manual even has examples … `userid?fields=context.fields(mutual_friends)`

Comment: I think then we can't help you. I tested this a few moments ago, and it works.

Comment: ok can you Give me the complete Example you test and works with you the complete one

Comment: No, I can't, because when using app-scoped user_ids, it only works with the respective app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, quite easy solution i have for you.

```
NSString *myFriendId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",#YourFriendId#];


    NSString *hashedAccessToken = [self hmac:accessToken withKey:kAPP_SECRETE];
    NSDictionary *params = @{
                             @"fields" : @"context.fields(mutual_friends)",
                             @"appsecret_proof" : hashedAccessToken,
                             @"access_token" : accessToken
                             };


    /* make the API call */
    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:myFriendId parameters:params  HTTPMethod:@"GET" completionHandler:^
     (
      FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error
      ){//Handle Respons;}];
```

And here is the hmac function (Add  #import )

```
//SHA256 HASHMAC
- (NSString *)hmac:(NSString *)access_token withKey:(NSString *)app_secret
{
    const char *cKey  = [app_secret cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    const char *cData = [access_token cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);
    NSData *HMACData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];
    const unsigned char *buffer = (const unsigned char *)[HMACData bytes];
    NSMutableString *HMAC = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:HMACData.length * 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < HMACData.length; ++i){
        [HMAC appendFormat:@"%02x", buffer[i]];
    }
    return HMAC;
}
```