# Is there a work around(permission) to get friendPickerFragment to show all friends?

Tags: android, facebook

I realized that the problem I was having on [Why is my friend picker fragment empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498106/why-is-my-friend-picker-fragment-empty) was that the fragment run fine, its just since i am using facebook graph version 2.0, it only shows the friends that are currently using the app(none, just me). Is there a workaround or some other permission you can use to have the fragment retrieve all friends, not just the ones using the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids

If you're using Graph API v2.0, the endpoint `/me/friends` will always only show the friends which are also using the app.

Quote:

> There are two key use cases where apps need access to non-app friends: tagging and inviting. In v2.0, we've added the Taggable Friends API and the Invitable Friends API to support these flows.

Links:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/invitable_friends/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/taggable_friends/

If you "just" want to show mutual friends which also use the app, you can use the

```
/{user_id}.context/mutual_friends
```

> ... `user_friends` permission is required to view the mutual friends of other friends using the app.

Have a look at my answer at [Fetch Facebook Mutual friends between me and another User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25223863/fetch-facebook-mutual-friends-between-me-and-another-user/25227620#25227620)

Comment: I did read that. But my app involves messaging(access to all friends), would there be some around this to access the user's complete friend list. I know tinder has an option where you see common friends with another match. That doesn't involve tagging or inviting

Comment: Therefore, you can use `/{user_id}.context/mutual_friends`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Tobi I noticed that on tinder you can also go to your profile and see friends. Does that mean they all use tinder?