# Can android friends list include non app user friends?

Tags: android, facebook

Going off my last question [Is there a work around(permission) to get friendPickerFragment to show all friends?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499560/is-there-a-work-aroundpermission-to-get-friendpickerfragment-to-show-all-frien), I noticed that when I go on my tinder profile, I can see a list of my friends. Based on the new upgrade to graph v 2.0, does that mean all of these friends(35+) use tinder, or did tinder find some workaround - taggable friends to show these friends even though they do not use tinder?(Profile -> My Friends)

Comment: You can see how many friends you have, so just compare this to the number in Tinder. In general, if it's a v2.0 app, it's not possible to get all friends. And please, don't ask the same question twice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a work around(permission) to get friendPickerFragment to show all friends?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499560/is-there-a-work-aroundpermission-to-get-friendpickerfragment-to-show-all-frien)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my many, many, many google searches and questions and what not, i've come to the following conclusion:

There is no way to get the entire Facebook friend list if you make an application right now.

The reason some apps are still able to get the full friend list, is that they were created prior to 31th May 2014 (Not 100% sure on the date, but around that time), so they were allowed access to the "old" API (The old API allows you to get a full friend list) until some time during the summer of 2015. This was done to allow them time to transistion to the new API (The new API only allows you to get a list of people that use your application, which is bullsh*t to be honest).

Sorry.

Comment: It's April 30th 2014. It's all in the docs, you just should read them :-) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v1tov2

Comment: Tobi you said here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499560/is-there-a-work-aroundpermission-to-get-friendpickerfragment-to-show-all-frien that you could use the taggable api. I try to use that without notifing the tagged user.

Comment: Yeah, but not for your use case.